# Use tf.TextLineReader to read to a np.array in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I need to read a file in my train module into a np.array (i want to use the array as label_keys in a DNNClassifier).

I tried tf.read_file and tf.TextLineReader() but i can´t get them to just output the rows to a np.array.

Is it possible?

(why not just read a file with open? I´m training in GCS and want to get the file from storage :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a file from GCS using TensorFlow, you can use the Python [`tf.gfile.GFile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/GFile) API, which  acts like a regular Python file object, but allows you to use TensorFlow's filesystem connectors:

```
with tf.gfile.GFile("gs://...") as f:
  file_contents = f.read()
```